# TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined in react error

Tags: reactjs

i am beginner , i want to decode token but showing error

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

function parseJwt(token) {
var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(atob(base64).split('').map(function (c) {
    return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
}).join(''));
return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
};
```

Navbar
E:/simplecloneig/src/components/Navbar.js:20

```
function Navbar() {
const history = useHistory()


if(Cookies.get('access') === undefined) history.push('/login')
const token = parseJwt(Cookies.get('access'));

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        const M = window.M;
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
        M.Dropdown.init(elems, {});
});
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O, you can format put your code using code block ``` rather that quote >. This makes the code more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the token may possibly be `undefined` as the error msg stated.

First thing you can do is to try to `console.log(token)` to see whether it makes sense.